# SSIS Count of Object Variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, bids

I am using SSIS in BIDS 2008 and I am trying to get a count of an Object Variable containing a list of files. Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: An SSIS variable of type Object has been assigned something that exposes a Count property and you would like to get that value?

Comment: Yes, I would like to get that value, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you populating this Object Variable?  Depending on how you populate the variable, more eligant ways of getting the count can be listed.  However, here is a quick and dirty solution for you:

1. Create a new variable of type integer and initialize the variable to 0
2. Use a foreach loop task to iterate over your object (open the foreach loop editor, go to `Collections` and change the Enumerator to `Foreach ADO Enumerator` and the ADO object source variable to your Object variable.
3. Create a `Execute SQL Task`
4. On the general tab, set ResultSet to Single row and your sql statement to  `SELECT (@Count + 1)`
5. In the Parameter Mapping tab, add your new integer variable and change the `Parameter Name` attribute to @Count
6. In the Result Set tab, add a new entry with name: 0 and variable name: your newly created integer variable.

Once your looping completes, you will have the count of the object.

NOTE: If you are already iterating through these files (which I assume you are since you are using SSIS to populate an Object Variable with file names), you need only perform steps 1, 3-6.

Comment: Sounds great, that's what I was afraid of. I wish during debugging you could see the values an object contains and just easily do an Object.Count. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you don't just use a script task?

Given two SSIS variables, MyObject (type Object) and MyObjectCount (Int32) set to 10.

Script task 1 fills the object.

```
    // Nothing clever, just fills a List<T> with 
    // MyObjectCount's worth of values.
    public void Main()
    {
        int count = (Int32)Dts.Variables["User::MyObjectCount"].Value;
        List<bool> obj = new List<bool>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            obj.Add(false);
        }

        Dts.Variables["User::MyObject"].Value = obj;
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Script task 2 simply assigns the value of the SSIS variable MyObject into a local variable which I cast into the appropriate type. I compare that count to my reference count and they are the same.

```
    public void Main()
    {
        int refCount = (Int32)Dts.Variables["User::MyObjectCount"].Value;
        List<bool> obj = Dts.Variables["User::MyObject"].Value as List<bool>;
        int actualCount = obj.Count;
        string message = string.Format("Reference count: {0}. Actual count {1}", refCount, actualCount);

        bool fireAgain = false;
        Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Accessing count", message, string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success; Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Results

[Accessing count] Information: Reference count: 10. Actual count 10

If you aren't responsible for what's pushing the object into the SSIS variable, then you might need to wrap the above extractions into a series of try/catch blocks or cast it as a type until you find something that the run-time *can* convert into a strongly typed object.

Answer (score 0):

The way I went about it, keep in mind I already had a ForEachLoop container that looped through excel files.

1. Created Count Variable with DataType=INT Value=1
2. Dragged Expression Task below my Data Flow and attached precedence
3. Inserted this function in the Expression Task

```
@[User::Count] = @[User::Count] + 1
```

Each time the file loops the Count variable will increase by 1.
Hope this Helps anyone searching this question.