# How to continue only if records present in SSIS

Tags: ssis

For this diagram:

[image: SSIS Package]

The "Get Score Files" Script obtains a list of files and puts them into a User Variable filelist (datatype object).  That list is THrown into the "Find Score Files" Loop, and will process each item on the list.

I need it to run ONLY if their's files to be had.  If the "Get Score Files" Script returns NO objects, I want the Package to End Successfuly.  How do I tell it to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Add a [expression constraint](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2006/10/30/using-constraints-and-expressions/) between Get Score Files and Truncate STAGE that checks the value of your variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS Count of Object Variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537403/ssis-count-of-object-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "get score file" try this code

```
  if (files.Count == 0)
            {
                Dts.Variables["files_present"].Value = false;

            }
            else
            {
                Dts.Variables["file_list"].Value =files;
                Dts.Variables["files_present"].Value = true;

            }`
```

In SSIS u should create one more variable(files_present) with bool type

Now in the precedence constraints expression before for each loop use files_present variable to check any file present or not`(if true file present else no files)

Comment: var  files= new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles("D:\\SSIS_PRACTICE\\Acrobatci_files")); // to get directry

Comment: annd in for each loop use For each from variable enumerator